# Где хранятся списки файлов, которые могут запускаться при старте системы?

Tags: windows, winapi

Подскажите, правильно ли я понимаю, что автозагрузка работает из трех источников: реестра, автозапуска и планировщика задач?

Answer (score 2):

> правильно ли я понимаю, что автозагрузка работает из трех источников: реестра, автозапуска и планировщика задач?

Нет. Вы путаете тёплое с мягким. Источник один - файлы на диске (в.т.ч. и сетевом). А кто ту или иную ерунду с диска запустит - вот тут вариантов немерено. WinInit, Explorer или ещё какой модуль, в т.ч. и по цепочке...

Если желаете посмотреть ВСЁ, где и что теоретически может запускаться при старте, используйте соотв. программы. Например, [AutoRuns](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx).

И учитывайте, что любой автозапущенный модуль может запустить что-то ещё - такой ерунды уже ни одна программа не учтёт. Тогда разве что смотреть список запущенных процессов (например, с помощью [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)) и пытаться определить, кто же запустил тот или иной модуль - авось дерево пап и дочек процессов поможет. А если папа выгрузился, и очередной автозапустившийся модуль ни к чему не привязан - тогда только мониторинг загрузки. Скажем, с помощью [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).